# Got "message": "Forbidden, error: code=403, message=Forbidden" when I am doing curl command

Tags: curl

I am trying to run IOTA hornet node on docker for my project.
when I want to get information of the node, I am doing `curl -s http://localhost:14265 -X POST -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"command": "/health"}' | jq`.
As the result, I have an error 403 massage. Can't understand what is going on. Can somebody help please ?

I am using config.json from https://github.com/gohornet/hornet/tree/v1.0.3
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this, you have

```
"jwtAuth": {
"enabled": false,
"salt": "HORNET"
},
```

then you can check info in bash using

```
curl localhost:14265/api/v1/info
```